# Need help with smart contract

Tags: solidity, ethereum-wallet-dapp

My code on Solidity is:

```
contract Recoverable is Ownable {

  /// @dev Empty constructor (for now)
  function Recoverable() public {
  }

  /// @dev This will be invoked by the owner, when owner wants to rescue tokens
  /// @param token Token which will we rescue to the owner from the contract
  function recoverTokens(ERC20Basic token) onlyOwner public {
    token.transfer(owner, tokensToBeReturned(token));
  }

  /// @dev Interface function, can be overwritten by the superclass
  /// @param token Token which balance we will check and return
  /// @return The amount of tokens (in smallest denominator) the contract owns
  function tokensToBeReturned(ERC20Basic token) public returns (uint) {
    return token.balanceOf(this);
  }
}
```

And I get next error: `Function state mutability can be restricted to view
  function tokensToBeReturned(ERC20Basic token) public returns (uint) {
  ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).`

I take this example from GitHub, and when I try куdeclare a function as `internal pure`, then get the next error:

```
function declared as pure, but this expression (potentially) reads from the environment or state and thus requires "view".
    return token.balanceOf(this);
                           ^--^
```

P.S. Help me, I really don`t understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tokensToBeReturned` is a function that does not alter the state of the blockchain. It's just reading from it: it read the balance of the current contract. Therefore, a node could call it without creating a transaction.

A function that doesn't alter the state, should be declared as `view`, which means that nodes can decide not to create a transaction in order to get it's return value.

Functions declared as `pure` can not even read from the blockchain state. They can only return values that are either fully dependent on the calldata, or constant.

change

```
function tokensToBeReturned(ERC20Basic token) public returns (uint) {
    return token.balanceOf(this);
}
```

to

```
function tokensToBeReturned(ERC20Basic token) public view returns (uint) {
    return token.balanceOf(this);
}
```

Documentation links:

- [`view`](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/contracts.html#view-functions)
- [`pure`](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/contracts.html#pure-functions)

Comment: Shuld I declared all functions as `view` or `pure`? What`ll hapens if I don`t set it?

Comment: Check out the pages to which I added links

Comment: so why `function canUpgrade() public view returns(bool) {
     return true;
  }` is wrong and compilator ask: Function state mutability can be restricted to pure
?

Comment: Because `canUpgrade` does not alter the state, **AND** it does not read from it. It just returns `true`, a constant.